# Is it possible to print the Object values in a reverse in Javascript? If so what is the suggested solution

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to print it in the reverse order how can it be achieved in javascript

My real Object looks like this

```
{2018: {…}, 2019: {…}, 2020: {…}, 2021: {…}, 2022: {…}, 2023: {…}, 2024: {…}, 2025: {…}}
2018: {Jan: 0, Feb: 0, Mar: 0, Apr: 0, May: 0, …}
2019: {Jan: 0, Feb: 0, Mar: 0, Apr: 0, May: 0, …}
2020: {Jan: 0, Feb: 4, Mar: 0, Apr: 0, May: 0, …}
2021: {Jan: 0, Feb: 0, Mar: 0, Apr: 0, May: 1, …}
2022: {Jan: 0, Feb: 0, Mar: 0, Apr: 1, May: 0, …}
2023: {Jan: 0, Feb: 0, Mar: 0, Apr: 1, May: 0, …}
2024: {Jan: 0, Feb: 0, Mar: 1, Apr: 0, May: 0, …}
2025: {Jan: 0, Feb: 0, Mar: 1, Apr: 0, May: 0, …}
```

I want to print it in the reverse order

Comment: Create an array -> go through in reverse and print values

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: `let arr = Object.keys(obj); arr.reverse(); arr.forEach(key => console.log(obj[key]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply solution should be converting the key attributes to array and sort and use it.

```
var statsCheck = Object.keys( Obj); 
     statsCheck = statsCheck.sort( function ( a, b ) { return b - a; } ); 
   for ( var i = 0; i < statsCheck.length; i++ )
{console.log(statsCheck[i]);}
```